# Jena Eyeball maxCardinality

Tags: java, jena

I am using Jena Eyeball validator and i have some problems with cardinality.
If i add tag

```
<owl:cardinality>1</owl:cardinality>
```

the eyeball catch that tag, also if i add

```
<owl:minCardinality>1</owl:minCardinality>
```

it will throw some message if the wanted line is not in the request.

My problems came with

```
<owl:maxCardinality>
```

when i set it to 1 nothing happens...

I tried to add minCardinality 0 and maxCardinality 1 but when i add some line 2 times jena eyeball does not catch the maxCardinality...

So is there some other way to catch the maxCardinality?

Comment: [there is no Apache release of Eyeball and the code has not been updated for Jena3](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/eyeball-getting-started.html)

Comment: I am not using Apache version i am using the old one..

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jena/Scratch/Eyeball/trunk/

Comment: There is a W3C standard for data validation: SHACL.  And an open source implementation that works with Jena : https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i implemented my logic in Jena Eyeball, now i can validate the objects like i want.

Comment: And also about SHACL the bad thing is  : Currently only Turtle (.ttl) files are supported. And i need it for RDF/XML